# QueueUserWorkItem() performance issues using Mono C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, threadpool, queueuserworkitem

I'm getting intermittent spikes in my profiler around the call to QueueUserWorkItem(). I queue roughly 20 jobs every second. Each job is roughly identical in terms of complexity. 95% of the jobs spend less than 0.01ms in the call to QueueUserWorkItem. But every few seconds, seemingly at random, a job will take from 20-60ms!

I'm trying to build a smooth simulation and just queuing my background tasks is causes serious hitches in my framerate.

This is not the time it takes for the job to actually FINISH, this is time spent on simply QUEUEING the job. Which I would expect should take virtually no time at all, so this is very frustrating.

```
foreach ( Job j in jobs_to_process )
{
    Job current_job = j;
    if ( !current_job.queued )
    {
        current_job.queued = true;

        Profiler.BeginSample("QueueWorkItem");
        ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem( current_job.DoCalculation, null );
        Profiler.EndSample();
    }
}

//now I remove queued items from jobs_to_process, move them to jobs_in_progress list
```

Things I've tried:

- Queuing fewer jobs per second only causes proportionately fewer hitches, but it still hitches.
- Putting lock(obj) around all access to job.queued variable
- Using SmartThreadPool instead of defaultThreadPool. Problem still
  persists inside STP's QueueWorkItem()

Comment: Are you able to run it on Windows, to see if this is a Mono problem?

Comment: Seems to me like you might be getting contention on the task queue now and then. When you're trying to add a task it's possible that the queue is locked by a thread trying to take work from the queue.

Comment: Drilling down a little further, I believe this is a problem with contention between threads. The profiler shows the time is spent inside QueueWorkItem's Monitor.Exit().
But how would I prevent this? Surely the lock around the queue should not persist for 60 milliseconds!

Comment: Henk - I am running it on the Window's version of Mono 2.6. I cannot swap Mono since it is a part of a much larger framework (Unity Engine).

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `--server` flag when running mono (only compatible with mono master, as it was committed recently).

Comment: I'm stuck on mono 2.6. Probably for another year or so. I was unable to find any reference to this flag. Can you tell me what it does and what I might expect if I were able to enable it? Thanks.